# Variation and jumps of spec. stochastic processeses

Tags: stochastic-processes

just wondering, why $\Delta[Var(X)]_t=|\Delta X_t|$ holds for cadlag, adapted and increasing real valued processes X with finite variation over all finite intervals $[0,t]$, which are in addition uniform integrable martingales? $Var(X)_t$ denotes the variation of a process $X$ over the interval $[0,t]$.  Any help?

It is mentioned in the proof of Lemma 3.11 in the book Limit theorems for stochastic processes by Shyraev/Jacod.

Comment: By "variation" do you perhaps mean "quadratic variation"?

Comment: No, it is supposed to mean the normal variation.

Comment: Can you define all of the notation you are using? It may not necessarily be standard. (In particular, I am not sure what type of stochastic process the $\Delta$ is supposed to signify.)

Comment: Well, $\Delta X$ at time t is just $X_t-X_{t_-}$. I will add the remaining definitions later, but they are all defined in the book mentioned.

Comment: @William I would say the remaining definitions are standard.

Comment: @Math1000 Sorry, forgot to tag you.